# currvita - vertical distance between bullters

Tags: spacing, itemize, cv, currvita

How to make smaller vertical distance between item bullets in one section only ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[TextAligned,NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{John Doe}

\begin{cvlist}{Sec1}
\item[2000-01--2012-12] x
\item[2000-01--2012-12] y
\item[2000-01--2012-12] z
\end{cvlist}

%how to change vertical distance between items in on section only, leaving other sections unaffected ?
\begin{cvlist}{Section that needs smaller vertical distance}
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\end{cvlist}

\begin{cvlist}{SecN}
\item[2000-01--2012-12] x
\item[2000-01--2012-12] y
\item[2000-01--2012-12] z
\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by putting

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{%
        -0.50\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt%
      }%
```

inside the `cvlist` environment where you want to reduce the spacing

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[TextAligned,NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{John Doe}

\begin{cvlist}{Sec1}
\item[2000-01--2012-12] x
\item[2000-01--2012-12] y
\item[2000-01--2012-12] z
\end{cvlist}

%change the values in itemsep appropriately
\begin{cvlist}{Section that needs smaller vertical distance}
\setlength{\itemsep}{%
        -0.50\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt%
      }%
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\item[2000-01--2012-12] A
\end{cvlist}


\begin{cvlist}{SecN}
\item[2000-01--2012-12] x
\item[2000-01--2012-12] y
\item[2000-01--2012-12] z
\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great thanks ! You've saved a lot of space on my CV :)

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Welcome.

Comment: @HarishKumar: How can I set the vertical space between items globally for all cvlist enviroments?

Comment: @Robinaut: Put this after loading `currvita` package: `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0ex}}{\setlength{\itemsep}{-0.50\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt}}{}{}`